# Flash cannot setup XMLSocket

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sockets, xmlsocket

I just started a project in flash, but it can't startup XMLSocket.

My code:

```
import Network.CommunicationBootstrap;

var network:CommunicationBootstrap = new CommunicationBootstrap();
network.start("127.0.0.1", 30000);
```

Package Network classs CommunicationBootstrap:

```
package Network {
import flash.net.XMLSocket;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;

public class CommunicationBootstrap {

    private var socket:XMLSocket = new XMLSocket();

    public function CommunicationBootstrap() {
        socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
        socket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
    }

    public function start(ip:String, port:int):void {
        this.socket.connect(ip, port);

        trace("Testing this out!");
    }

    private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
        trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
    }

    private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
        trace("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
    }

}

}
```

What my errors are:
ioErrorHandler: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2031: Socket Error. URL: 127.0.0.1"]
securityErrorHandler: [SecurityErrorEvent type="securityError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: file:///C|/Users/iufrs/Documents/AS3/1/Torn.swf cannot load data from 127.0.0.1:30000."]

(gotten by trace and the 2 events)

Comment: did you set up crossdomain.xml?

Answer (score 1):

This is (as the message hints) due to the sandbox your swf is running in.

from [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3f.html)

> Local file describes any file that is referenced by using the file:
>   protocol

Which is what you are doing here.

Further:

> The local-with-filesystem sandbox—For security purposes, Flash Player
>   places all local SWF files and assets in the local-with-file-system
>   sandbox, by default. From this sandbox, SWF files can read local files
>   (by using the URLLoader class, for example), but they cannot
>   communicate with the network in any way. This assures the user that
>   local data cannot be leaked out to the network or otherwise
>   inappropriately shared

This is what is causing you to see the error.

If you intend your swf to be hosted by a web server, then you should make sure the swf can be loaded from your webserver running on `127.0.0.1`, and you should load it over http, e.g. as `http://127.0.0.1/YourSwf.swf`

If you want to run your sef from the filesystem, you need to compile it to run in the 'local-with-networking' sandbox, the link explains how.

.